# How to auto increment a number in mailbody?

Tags: php, html

I want to send a mail to my customer, and in the body i want a value which will be multiplied by 2 after 60 minutes.

Suppose at 3.00 PM. i saw '10' in my mail body, then at 4.00 PM. I will be seeing '20 in my mail body

I am using PHP script to send the mail.

I want $result of this line to be multiplied by 2 after 60 minute

So if you open your shop 24*7 then your aprroximated revenue will be **$result**

Thank you !!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/* subject and email varialbles*/
session_start();
$emailSbuject = 'New Client Details';
$webMaster = 'vivek@h.com';
$emailSbuject2 = 'Thank you for calculating your revenue';
$client = ' $emailFeild\r\n';
/*gathering data variables*/

$nameFeild = $_POST['name'];
$phoneFeild = $_POST['phone'];
$emailFeild = $_POST['email'];
$dayFeild = $_POST['day'];
$timeFeild = $_POST['time'];
$revenueFeild = $_POST['revenue'];
$result = (($revenueFeild*7*24)/($dayFeild*$timeFeild));

// admin message body
$body= <<<EOD
Contact Form Details of $nameFeild

Name: $nameFeild \n
Email: $emailFeild \n
Contact Phone: $phoneFeild \n
Revenue: $result \n
EOD;
// Client message body
$body2 = <<<EOD

<p style="margin-left:10px;font-family:Calibri"><img alt=""         src="http://www.h.com.au/images/logo.gif"></p>

Dear $nameFeild,



         <p style="font-family:Calibri">Thank you for contacting me. One of our representatives will contact you the soonest. If you have more questions or information needed, please let us know. We are happy to serve you ! </p>
     <p style="font-family:Calibri;color:maroon">How 24*7 can impact your business ?</p>
     <p style="font-family:Calibri">24*7 means, if you are located in kolkata,people of kolkata is no longer your only "would be customers".
     Rather the people of the entire globe will be able to see and discover your services and materials. Can you afford to lose their attention ego can see and disscover
     your materials and services ? 
     <br />
     <br />
     Do you NOT want to sell your stuff to a person from New York? And 6 PM, which is the generally accepted time for purhasing something(after their office hours), from
     your establishment at New York means your Indian Time 3:30 AM. Do you still think, you can afford to lose it ?
     </p>
     <p style="font-family:Calibri;color:maroon">Our Simple Math Solution</p>
     <p style="font-family:Calibri">If you have 100,000 rupees per month revenue, and you are taking 15 days time to think over this solution, you are potentially losing an opportunity to gain by INR 133,333/2 = Rs. 68,517/- . In case you are having a revenue of 500,000 per month, your 15 days indecision will cost you INR 3,42,585. And you can potentially <strong>STOP this drain by paying us INR 15,000 as soon as possible.</strong></p>
     <p style="font-family:Calibri;color:maroon">You gave <strong>$dayFeild</strong> as your shop opening days per week, <strong>$timeFeild</strong> as your shop opening hours per day and <strong>$revenueFeild</strong> as your approximated revenue
     <br />
     So if you open your shop 24*7 then your aprroximated revenue will be <strong>$result</strong></p>
     <p style="font-family:Calibri;color:maroon">So dont waste your time. Time is running. CALL US NOW</p>

     <p style="font-family:Calibri">my Team 


          <br> http://www.s.com <br> help@s.com </p>




<p  style="font-size:x-small;color:#0099FF;font-family:Calibri">This e-mail     was automatically sent by me Administration Directory and is for your reference. Please do not reply to this e-mail address.<br>
Powered by me.</p>
```

```
EOD;
    $headers = "From: $emailFeild\r\n";
    $header = "From: $noreply@me.com\nMIME-Version:     1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster,$emailSbuject,$body,$headers);
    $success1 = @mail($emailFeild,$emailSbuject2,$body2,$header);
    /*Result*/


    $theResults = <<<EOD
EOD;

echo  "$theResults";
$_SESSION['result'] = $result;
header("Location: thankyou.php");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Please show you code you have written so far?

Comment: Done sir. Please check and help me :)

Comment: Will this mail start at specific time? like 1 am value is 50 then at 2 am value is 100 and so on.. What will be the time of first mail?

Comment: Timer should start from the time when a user pressed the send button.

Comment: Please sir help me :)

Comment: Ok so the first mail will be triggered when users clicks on send button and then how will the mail after every 60 seconds will go to the user?

Comment: No sir. That number will be multiplied by 2 in the same mail after every 60 minute

Comment: OK, what I understood now is that mail will be sent only once and after each 60 minutes value will get multiplied by 2 on that mail in users inbox.?

Comment: Yes sir. Absolutely right.

Comment: Once you have sent the mail to someone with some content, how do you think you can change the content you had already sent? This does not seems to be possible. You can send another mail for that. What do you say?

Comment: then is their any way that they will get a mail automatically with the updated value ?

Comment: Write a cron job which will send mail with updated values?

Comment: can you give me any refference link